# sending packets on particular VLAN

Tags: switch, vlan

Is it possible for a computer to be part of 2 VLANs in an L2 switched network?
I have been working on creating a multicast network in a Layer 2 network. I thought that creating a VLAN for the multicast receivers would solve the issue of broadcasting packets in Layer 2. But what if my receivers want to be a part of the regular network? How do I make sure that the receivers can receive packets from the regular network and the VLAN? And finally, if the answer for above question is yes, then how do I configure a Cisco Layer 2 switch to do this?

Comment: You should split that up in multiple questions.

Comment: But it would void the context in the next question @GeraldSchneider. Anyways, could you help me with the situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible for a computer to [be] part of 2 VLANs in an L2
>   switched network?

A computer can have multiple (logical) network interfaces, but each interface can be on only one VLAN.

> I thought that creating a VLAN for the multicast receivers would solve
>   the issue of broadcasting packets in layer2.

The best solution to this is to use a switch with IGMP snooping